# Can a task that is generated from a workflow set off a time trigger to fire another task?

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have a task that generates when a record is created off a Custom OBject.  I tried to create another workflow on the Task object that would fire when that task is generated, but it did not work.  The workflow works fine when I create a task manually, but when the task is created through another workflow, it doesn't trigger the workflow on the Task object.

Has anyone else run into a situation where they wanted a workflow to fire another workflow, is this not possible through workflows?  Are there any ideas on how to do this through Apex?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I misread the Idea initially and did more research.

Yes, workflows can trigger other workflows. There is [a request](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrrCAAS) for it and it was delivered Spring '12. Going through the Salesforce documentation offers an idea: Time-based workflows [need a default user](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_wfrules.htm); do you have one configured?

Comment: -That linked idea says "Delivered in Spring 12"...

Comment: Not enough coffee? thanks for catching that, though. Post updated accordingly.

Comment: It's true that a Workflow Field Update can trigger another Workflow Rule if "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change" is checked on the Field Update. However, the situation here involves a Task that is *created* from a Workflow Rule on a parent object, then a Workflow Rule on the Task object that should run when a Task is created. There is no Field Update involved.